# Flutter barcode scan with black background issue

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a issue scanning barcode which has a black background. The scanner don’t scan the barcode only works if background is white.

Can you give me any advice what I can do in this situation?

I tried almost all available packages on pub.dev but unfortunately no one works for me.

Comment: How about inverting the black and white just before loading the image data into the scanner program?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner) package, it works for me.